# Bluepy make not working

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to install Bluepy from Github. I have downloaded both the zipped files and with

```
git clone https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy.git
```

But when I `cd` into the directory and run `make` I get three of the same error:

```
"./bluez-5.47/attrib/gatt.c:980:9: warning: ‘g_memdup’ is deprecated:
Use 'g_memdup2' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]"
```

I have opened `./bluez-5.47/attrib/gatt.c` in a text editor and replaced the three instances of  `g_memdup` with `g_memdup2` and saved the file. But when I run `make` I still get the same warnings.

I have tried deleting the directory and re-cloning the files and changed all three instances of `g_memdup` to `g_memdup2` before running `make`, but the warning about `g_memdup` being deprecated still appears. How can I change the `./bluez-5.47/attrib/gatt.c` file properly to remove this error?

Comment: I would try https://github.com/Mausy5043/bluepy3 as it was updated a couple weeks ago, the one you tried hasn't been updated in 2 years

Answer (score 0):

Warnings aren't usually interpreted as errors. As long as it builds, you should be okay without editing anything.

I'm pretty sure `-Wdeprecated-declarations` was added for backwards compatibility so that newer versions of gcc will not fail with an error.

Unless you're worried about [the vulnerabilities of `g_memdup`](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/port-your-module-from-g-memdup-to-g-memdup2-now/5538), you should be fine. And of interest, it is mentioned in that announcement that simply finding and changing `g_memdup` to `g_memdup2` is not sufficient.